# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Oompa Loompa\x07\x08'

Tags: tcp, tcpserver

I have the TCP server set up for receiving messages from connected clients, but when the message contains packed hex e.g "Oompa Loompa\x07\x08" it shows me this error:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Oompa Loompa\x07\x08'

I guess I have decoding issue in the code but I don't know how to fix it.

```
import socket
import threading

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = "192.168.1.103"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False

            print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")
            conn.send("Msg received".encode(FORMAT))

    conn.close()


def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[Active Clients] {threading.active_count() - 1}")


print("[BOOTING] server is starting...")
start()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like hex is a strings and needs to be an int. Try sending that message in binary.

Comment: Still no change. I have to somehow convert the "\x07\x08" into a string, but I dont know how

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).